# Make [microsoft.mshtml] a synonym for [mshtml]

Tags: support, status-declined, retag-request, synonym-request

I think [microsoft.mshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft.mshtml) should be a synonym for [mshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mshtml) (or vice versa, but mshtml is more common).

Comment: Questions tagged with [tag:microsoft.mshtml] should be tagged with [tag:mshtml] if not already. [tag:microsoft.mshtml] is a monstrosity IMO.

Comment: Hence the synonym, @Old. Perhaps a merge would be in order as well.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484791/mshtml-8-0-and-microsoft-mshtml-7-0) seems to indicate that there is some difference, however slight. I wasn't able to figure out a distinction in my brief searching, so is the OP of the linked question wrong?

Comment: Microsoft.Mshtml is going to be the .NET version of the library, placed into a "Microsoft" namespace and the DLL named to mirror this, according to convention. MSHTML is the name of the library itself, and was the original name of the native (unmanaged) DLL. @george

Comment: Even with this distinction, wouldn't it make sense to merge the stack exchange tags? After all, users can still express which version they use both in the text and by specifying additional language-specific tags. Right?

Comment: Yes, agreed. If there's a .NET-related tag, they're obviously using the .NET-specific version. I'm not sure whether there is really a big difference in the two APIs, but I highly doubt it. Furthermore, anyone who is an expert (or interested) in MsHTML is going to be able to answer questions about both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSHTML is the type library name and is used in any language that supports Automation interop.

Microsoft.mshtml is a PIA name.  A file that's located elsewhere and is only ever used by .NET programmers.  The declarations look very different.  But otherwise represents the same object model.

Convincing a C++ or Delphi programmer that Microsoft.mshtml has anything to do with his problem is going to be an uphill battle.  And it is pretty unlikely that any of the answers with this tag are helpful to them, COM programming in C++ is pretty fundamentally different.  It is therefore better to not make them synonyms.